# Element does not responding to setStyle

Tags: javascript, html, css, qooxdoo

I am trying to move a qx.html.Element that it is in a widget.
so I create a listener to catch mouse down and a listener to catch mouse move etc etc. 
code in the qooxdoo [playground](http://tinyurl.com/lt33dfg%5d)

But a weird thing happens when I try to for example `setStyle("top","30px")`
the `getStyle("top")`  return  `"30px"`
but the element does not seems to responding to the changes.

I have try to use the `qx.html.Element.flush()` but nothing changes.

But when I try to resize the element `( setStyle("height","20px"))` this change works fine  ( example in commented section)

what I am missing here ?

why setStyle in resize (commented) section is working and setStyle in move section doesn't ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that the element has `position:static`. `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` values only affect the element if it has position other than `static` (`relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`).

Be warned though, changing the value of the `position` property can have important effects on the layout of the widget and the entire application.

Comment: Initialize the element with new qx.html.Element("div",{"position":"relative", "background-color":"green", "height":"20px", "width": "20px", "top": "0px"}); do the trick. :>